# Using ByVal in vb.net methods, what's the common practice?

Tags: vb.net, syntax, pass-by-value

In vb.net the methods have their parameters using ByVal by default, it's better practice / common practice to make it explicit?

For example:

With ByVal:

```
Private Sub MySub(ByVal Q As String)
{
   ' ...
}
End Sub
```

Without ByVal:

```
Private Sub MySub(Q As String)
{
   ' ...
}
End Sub
```

Comment: How can you remove the ByVal keyword, since it's automatically inserted by Visual Studio? Is there an option to turn it off that I missed?

Comment: When I remove it manually, and click on another line, then it's added again. I've just read that VS2010 SP1 doesn't include ByVal automatically anymore, so maybe that's the version you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx):

> It is good programming practice to include either the ByVal or ByRef keyword with every declared parameter.

And if you use Visual Studio, it defaults to inserting `ByVal` if you don't explicitly specify it.

Comment: This is true only till VS2008. Starting with VS2010, MS has removed the above statement from the MSDN page you have linked above. Try changing the VS selection at the top of that page and see.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with VS 2010 SP1, `ByVal` is [no longer automatically inserted](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/542271) by the IDE.

I personally think it's better not to insert `ByVal` manually, because:

1. it's the [default passing mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) anyway, if neither `ByVal` nor `ByRef` are explicitly specified.
2. omitting `ByVal` from method signature makes `ByRef` stand out.
3. it adds 'noise' to the code. VB.Net is already very verbose, no need to clutter the code with unnecessary `ByVal`s.

Answer (score 0):

It is common practice that a method arguments can be specified at ByValue or ByReference. In VB.NET, the default argument type is `ByVal`. In many programming language, method arguments are `by-value` by default. If argument is not qualified with `ByVal` or `ByRef` then the argument type will be ByVal.